# .net strongly typed view Model not set to instance of object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I am creating a strongly-typed view. My model is called RestaurantReview.cs and looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OdeToFood.Models
{
    public class RestaurantReview
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I had Visual Studio create a strongly-typed List model  based on this, which looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantReview>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

When I run the site, I get a null pointer exception in the line "@foreach (var item in Model)", highlighting Model object, and stating "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Not really understanding how this code can be wrong since I didn't even write it, Visual Studio did. What is happening here?

Comment: Can you show controller action code returning this view? Your model should be instantiated there.

Comment: How does your `Controller` looks like? Do you pass any `IEnumrable<RestaurantView>` from your `Home` Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Controller` show have the `RestaurantReview` `IEnumerable` passed. Example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller { //suppose this is your Home
    public ActionResult Index() {
        IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantReview> model;
        model = from m in db.RestaurantReviews
                ... //your query here
                select m;
        return View(model); //pass the model here
    }
```

Then you will not get `null` exception

Comment: I see what I did. I forgot to include the parameter in "return View()." When I changed it to "return View(model)" it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @jimboweb great! ;) yes, that is typically the issue...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you haven't instantiated your model correctly within the `Controller`.

As a test you could try this:

```
public ActionResult Reviews()
{
   var model = new List<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantReview>();
   model.Add(new OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantReview { Name = "Test" });
   model.Add(new OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantReview { Name = "Test2" });

   return View(model);
}
```

However the model should be correctly populated from the DB.  If you can paste your Controller code that would help.